# Encrypt/Decrypt DB fields in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-5, eloquent

I am encrypting/decrypting the DB field values in Laravel through accessors and mutators, which is working fine in normal eloquent transactions.

```
class Person extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $table = 'person';

    public function getFirstNameAttribute($value)
    {
        return Crypt::decryptString($value);
    }
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = array();

    protected function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'useraccount_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

But the encryption and decryption not working under the following conditions

1. Eloquent relationships
2. DB raw queries

Working

```
$person = Person::find($person_id);
$person->firstName;
```

Not Working

```
$user = User::find($user_id);
$user->person->firstName;
```

Comment: You might want to checkout https://github.com/delatbabel/elocryptfive

Comment: Yes I tried that plugin and that too not working

Comment: How are you calling that method can you show the code please

Comment: Working
**********
$person = Person::find($person_id);
$person->firstName;

Not Working
**************
$user = User::find($user_id);
$user->person->firstName;

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: No error
The value is not decrypted and it displays the encrypted data

Comment: @KalyanaKannan Try `$user->person->first_name`, custom attributes get converted to snake_case automatically.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with laravel's **Crypt** Facades.
please follow this example.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

$encrypted = Crypt::encryptString('Hello world.');

$decrypted = Crypt::decryptString($encrypted);
```

I implemented from this article link : https://hackthestuff.com/article/laravel6-encryption-and-decryption-model-data-using-crypt-class

Answer (score 4):

Based on Iman his answer i changed the trait so it works with the casts array from Laravel self.

```
<?php
namespace App\Library\Traits;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
trait Encryptable
{
    /**
     * If the attribute is in the encryptable array
     * then decrypt it.
     *
     * @param  $key
     *
     * @return $value
     */
    public function getAttribute($key)
    {
        $value = parent::getAttribute($key);

        if (isset($this->casts[$key]) && $value !== '' && !is_null($value) && $this->casts[$key] == 'encrypt') {
            $value = decrypt($value);
        }
        return $value;
    }
    /**
     * If the attribute is in the encryptable array
     * then encrypt it.
     *
     * @param $key
     * @param $value
     */
    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        if (isset($this->casts[$key]) && $value !== '' && !is_null($value) && $this->casts[$key] == 'encrypt') {
            $value = encrypt($value);
        }
        return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
    /**
     * When need to make sure that we iterate through
     * all the keys.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function attributesToArray()
    {
        $attributes = parent::attributesToArray();
        foreach ($this->casts as $key => $value) {
            if($value == 'encrypt') {
                if (isset($attributes[$key]) && $attributes[$key] !== '' && !is_null($attributes[$key])) {
                    $attributes[$key] = decrypt($attributes[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
        return $attributes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

trait Encryptable
{
    protected function encryptValue($value)
    {
        $key = env('SALT_KEY'); // Replace this with your actual salt key
        $cipher = 'AES-128-CBC';
        $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
        $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($value, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, true);
        $ciphertext = base64_encode($iv . $hmac . $ciphertext_raw);

        return $ciphertext;
    }

    protected function decryptValue($value)
    {
        $key = env('SALT_KEY'); // Replace this with your actual salt key
        $cipher = 'AES-128-CBC';
        $c = base64_decode($value);
        $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
        $iv = substr($c, 0, $ivlen);
        $hmac = substr($c, $ivlen, 32);
        $ciphertext_raw = substr($c, $ivlen + 32);
        $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        $calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, true);

        return hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac) ? $original_plaintext : null;
    }


    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        if ($this->isEncryptableAttribute($key)) {
            $value = $this->encryptValue($value);
        }

        return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }

    public function getAttribute($key)
    {
        $value = parent::getAttribute($key);

        if ($this->isEncryptableAttribute($key) && !empty($value)) {
            $value = $this->decryptValue($value);
        }

        return $value;
    }

    protected function isEncryptableAttribute($key)
    {
        return in_array($key, $this->encryptable ?? []);
    }
}
```

First you make the traits with your own salt that is in the `.env` file named as `SALT_KEY` for better security and then you can use this trait in your model like this:

```
 use HasFactory,Encryptable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'description', 'status',
    ];

    protected $encryptable = ['name','description'];
```