# Laravel encrypter sometimes does not work

Tags: laravel, encryption

I had a fully functional encrypt/decrypt method set with Laravel, I tested it properly and was working fine.

The other day I received an error saying `The Payload is Invalid` and started debugging: looks like the function is not working. So I tested again but it works fine if I'm the one creating the encrypted records, which doesn't make sense because it should either work or fail every single time. Again, the method is a simple encrypt/decrypt of a column named `password` in the database on a table named `servers`.

Any idea what the problem may be? Is it possible that Laravel encrypts for a specific user? If so, how can I encrypt for multiple users?

Comment: could you add your method implementation. otherwise harder to answer to your question.

Comment: @NuwanDharshana it's really basic, that's why I didn't explain it (I think it's irrelevant for this solution). It's this process https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48785932/encrypt-decrypt-db-fields-in-laravel

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution changing the encryption mechanism from

```
encrypt() -> decrypt()
```

to

```
Crypt::encryptString() -> Crypt::decryptString()
```

If anybody has an explanation why the second method works where the first doesn't, feel free to expand and you'll have my upvote