# Laravel Encription

Tags: mysql

Laravel provides standard data encryption/decryption methods, see [Encrypt/Decrypt DB fields in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48785932/encrypt-decrypt-db-fields-in-laravel). However, the APP_KEY attribute stored in the .env file is used as the shared key for encryption, see https://simonkollross.de/posts/encrypting-laravel-eloquent-attributes-using-a-custom-cast. Thus, any administrator of the hosting can easily access this key and decrypt the secret data. In my existing project, the data of each user is encrypted at the mySQL level under by his own key, that is the user's password for the application.
Is it possible to implement in Laravel Eloquent the ability to encrypt user data under his own password (key), which will be unknown for the server administrator?

Comment: That is not MySQL encryption. https://github.com/illuminate/encryption/blob/master/Encrypter.php

Comment: Ok. I see. But I was talking about a fundamental problem - one encryption key for all records in the database, and this key is freely available to the hosting administrator. I would like to use a unique key for each user, known only to himself.

Comment: So don't use the `Crypt` facade and create your own encrypter using, for example PGP.

Comment: "Is it possible to implement" - yes, most probably you can write code to achieve that. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks. But I was hoping that there are some standard Laravel Eloquent tools or free packages that allow you to encrypt records in the database under unique keys (each user has their own key).

Comment: At the moment, I have already implemented such encryption at the mySQL level. I get user password as key and encrypt / decrypt user data in database with mySQL functions AES_ENCRYPT() и AES_DECRYPT(). But in this time I want to do some refactoring. I want to use Laravel Eloquent and I'm trying to figure out how I can do this without using mySQL functions directly (only with Eloquent).